# how can change value of a div

Tags: php, javascript

```
"<div id="diva">this is div a</div>"
"<div id="divb"> this is div b</div>"
```

now how can I change the text of `div` dynamically by button click. here also mention that all text come from a database. when I click the button then it detects the `div` id and replace the text with desire text.

All code will be in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work once the page is being loaded:

```
document.getElementById('diva').innerHTML = 
  <?php echo functionThatReturnsSomeValue(); ?>;
```

Dynamically, you would need to do an AJAX call on the PHP file which outputs a value. You'd be better off if you used a JS framework such as jQuery, rather than implementing the AJAX call [yourself](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp).

Comment: So does `xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);`
  `xmlhttp.send();` returns data that is set via `innerHTML`

Answer (score 3):

PHP cannot modify the content of the page *after* it has been served to the browser.  However this would be trivial with a JavaScript Library such as jQuery.