# how do i change the content of a div using php

Tags: php, html

It doesn't exactly have to be a div, it can be anything, a article section a ...

I'm making a website for a university project, the website is similar to DropBox (file hosting website). NON COMMERCIAL!

I'm on the registration page at the moment and what I want to do is after the user presses the submit button I want to change the content of a div tag which is next to the field which is wrongly entered.

For example, if the user types in a password that is less than 3 characters long an "X" will appear in the div tag next to the password field and under the submit button a message will appear saying "Password must be more than 3 characters."

This is part of the code, not posting all of it because it's too long.

```
<form action="register.php" method="post" >
  <section>
    <article>Password*</article>
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" required="required"/>
    <div id="right_or_wrong"></div> <!-- tick - &#10003; , wrong - X -->
  </section>
  <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" />
<div id="error_msg"></div>
</form>
```

I have tried to search on how to do this but I can't find anything and I just can't figure it out.

I know I can put the PHP code in the div tag and assess it from there but I want to put the code at the bottom of the form to make it neater.

Comment: use http://jqueryvalidation.org/ to validate password character.

Comment: you're barking in the wrong forest. with php (server side) you can update the form following submission if the password is wrong - in this case you're modifying the response.  you really want to read about javascript. use something simple like jquery to monitor the value of `password` and react accordingly. https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: The short answer is that you just put the `<div>` in an `if` statement … but that leaves aside all the questions of how you use forms with PHP, and how you test if values match patterns. You should really start with an introductory PHP tutorial.

Comment: If you read what I wrote you will see "after the user presses the submit button", so if the user enters "abc" in the password field and presses submit or in my example Register then the page will reload as usual and the div element will now contain an "X" where before it didn't contain anything, it was empty

Comment: A lot of people are waving JavaScript around. JavaScript is great to make things convenient for users, but you *do* need to perform these tests on the server (you can't trust the user's browser to make the user conform to your requirements, it is under the user's control).

Comment: `<article>Password*</article>` — That is not an article! Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: This link may have some hints for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136365/how-can-change-value-of-a-div

Answer (score 1):

So in register.php when you validated the form and see that the password was too short, you can set a variable like `$password_error = "Password must be more than 3 characters."`.

Then you can just re-render the form and

```
<div id="right_or_wrong"><?php echo $password_error; ?></div>
```

Comment: that's the logical thing that i tried to do, but it doesn't update it :|

Answer (score 0):

You can validate before sending the form to the server, with simple onsubmit function:

```
<script>
function validate(){
    // here, check the password and other answers
    if( /* check password here */ ){
        document.getElementById("right_or_wrong_password").innerHTML="X";
        document.getElementById("error_msg").innerHTML="Password must be more than 3 characters.";
        return false; // prevent from submitting form
    }else if( /* check field1 here */ ){
        document.getElementById("right_or_wrong_field1").innerHTML="X";
        document.getElementById("error_msg").innerHTML="Error in the field......";
        return false; // prevent from submitting form
    }else{
        return true; // the form can be submitted
    }
}
</script>
<form action="register.php" method="post" >
  <section>
    <article>Password*</article>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required="required"/>
    <div id="right_or_wrong_password"></div> <!-- tick - &#10003; , wrong - X -->
  </section>
  <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" onsubmit="validate()" />
<div id="error_msg"></div>
</form>
```

In this way, you can verify each field of the form (answers structure only). Then a server validation is always necessary.

Answer (score -1):

PHP can't do that alone. PHP is server-scripting - it can't run on user's machine and handle live events.

Instead, use [Javascript's AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax) and call a php file which would return the text. And, then use Javascript to append that text to div or whatever you want.