# setting text in a <div> tag in PHP

Tags: php, web

I'm new to web development and have not had any luck finding an easy way to write to a div like I do in jquery.

this is my div in my HTML

```
<div id="message_line1" class="message">&nbsp;</div>
```

and in jQuery I do this to set an error message

```
var errorStatusHandle1 = $('#message_line1');
errorStatusHandle1.text("some error message");
```

works perfectly, so moving to PHP I would like to print the form in PHP but have no idea how to set the error to my div or if that is even possible. Any help is great appreciated.

Comment: Answered already here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136365/how-can-change-value-of-a-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a backend language. It is executed **on the server**, **not in the browser**. So if you to make any changes to the page without having to reload it *in the browser*, then you would use JavaScript. However, if you want to write the `div` at *page load time*,
then you would use the `print` (or `echo`) statement:

```
<div id="message_line1" class="message">
  <?php print $error_message; ?>
</div>
```

Note: Make sure it is saved as a PHP file. (`.php`)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this completely in PHP. Simply at the top of the page place:

```
<?php
$errorMSG = "Some Error Message";
?>
```

Then place this where you want the error message to show.

```
<?php echo $errorMSG; ?>
```

You can implement this in your code like this:

```
<div id="message_line1" class="message"><?php echo $errorMSG; ?></div>
```

Then using $errorMSG = ""; you can set the message using what ever error you want to show.

Ensure the file name ends with a .php not .html otherwise it wont work.